# JWPlayer only loading buy not play in IE 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, jwplayer

```
      jwplayer("mediaplayer").setup({
        provider: 'http',
        file: encodeURI(JWplayer_top_video_path),
        image: "http://vod.hkheadline.com/hkheadline/instant_video/2013/0103/6beae821acd0eaf1d59e0daa974f5836.jpg",

        //Player for IE,FF,Chrome
        flashplayer: "./js/jwplayer/player.swf",
        //Skin for IE,FF
        skin: "./js/jwplayer/skin/glow.zip",
        wmode: "opaque",
        width: 650,
        height: 390,
        stretching: "uniform",
        autostart: "false",
        autopreloading: "true",
        dock: "true",
        bufferlength: 10,

        plugins: {
        //  fbit: {enable: true},
        //  tweetit: {enable: true},
            "gapro-2":{ 
                "trackstarts": true,
                "trackpercentage": true,
                "trackseconds": true,
                "tracktime": true
                }
        },

        modes: [
            { type: "html5",
                //Skin for Chrome
                config: {skin: "./js/jwplayer/skin/glow/glow.xml"}
            },
            { type: "flash", src: "./js/jwplayer/player.swf" }
        ],

        'events': {
            onComplete: function(e){
                $('#mediaplayer').remove();
                close_overlay();
            }
        }
      });
```

The above code is the setup jwplayer. It works perfectly on chrome, fx, safari , but not in IE8. In Ie 8 the player is shown and I can click on the play button, However, it keeps loading and loading but never play the movie, how to fix the problem ?thanks

Comment: Can you provide a link to where this code is running? Thanks.

Comment: possibly due to not update flash player. thanks